# Rebuild Widget with ValueKey() in release mode but not working

Tags: flutter, dart

My app wants `Widget` to be updated by changing the value of `ValueKey()` in certain situations.

```
return Platform.isAndroid
        ? MaterialApp(
      key: ValueKey(context.watch<PDFProvider>().keyCount),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: _displayPhoneMainScreen(context, _size),
      ),
    )
        : CupertinoApp(
      key: ValueKey(context.watch<PDFProvider>().keyCount),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      home: CupertinoPageScaffold(
        child: _displayPhoneMainScreen(context, _size),
      ),
    );
```

I thought that the function was implemented without problems because I developed it in `debug mode`, but when I tested it in `release mode`, I found out that `ValueKey()` value was changed but `Widget` was not updated.

I've searched the problem with several keywords, but haven't found an answer yet. Is there a way to update a `Widget` with a `key` value in release mode?

**Edit**
I will write example code.

```
PDFView(
            key: ValueKey(context.watch<PDFProvider>().keyCount),
            pdfData: context.read<PDFProvider>().uinPdfData!,
            enableSwipe: true,
            swipeHorizontal: true,
            autoSpacing: false,
            pageFling: false,
            defaultPage: nDefaultPage,
            onRender: (_pages) {
              setState(() {
                isReady = true;
                nDefaultPage = 0;
              });
            },
            onError: (error) {
              print(error.toString());
            },
            onPageError: (page, error) {
              print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
            },
            onPageChanged: (int? page, int? total) {
              setState(() {
                nPageIndex = page! + 1;
                // context.read<PDFProvider>().setTotalStffNum(total!);
              });
            },
          ),
```

I display a pdf on screen with the `flutter_pdfview` package. pdf will change according to certain options. Therefore, when an option is changed, the value of `ValueKey()` must be increased so that the previous `key` value and the current `key` value are different, so it must be updated. But this works fine in `debug` but not in `release`.

Inside `_displayPhoneMainScreen` there is a `PDFView`. Applying `key` to `MaterialApp` is not reflected in `release`. But `ketCount` increments normally.

Also, when rebuilding due to a change in `key`, the image should be redrawn, but it does not respond.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more like how this is suppose to change the widget? From your example it looks like its changing the widget based on platform not on key.  Are you talking about updating the whole material app based on key?

Comment: Added code as requested. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have a mechanism to reload the PDFView, create a property in the widget:

```
var pdfViewerKey = UniqueKey();
...
PDFView(
     key: pdfViewerKey,
...
```

then when you want to reload the PDFView, generate a new UniqueKey() like so:

```
setState(() {
  pdfViewerKey = UniqueKey();
});
```